# How to change an old Microsoft Visual C# 2010 express 32bit project to 64bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have a project that was build in Microsoft Visual C# Express 2010. The program was originally built as a 32-bit application, and I want to change that to a 64-bit application.

How can I do that?

Comment: you don't have the target option in express?

Comment: @alexb I forgot to mention that it is my very first project on visual express stuff. So, I am not sure where to find the target option.

Comment: @wael34218 Ahh forgot about that. I dont think the option is available with the Express version. You're most likely stuck with x86 unless there is some kind of way around it.

Comment: It _is_ possible in the express edition. See my answer.

Comment: @wael34218 I don't have express but here is how it is in non-express: right click on your project -> Properties -> Build tab -> General Section -> Platform Target (Any CPU, x86, x64, Itanium)

Comment: @wael34218 ... or if you don't have a Project node in Solution Explorer you search in menu for Build -> Configuration Manager -> Platform dropdown -> New and you should be able to see all platform targets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600162/difference-between-bin-debug-and-bin-release/11601057#11601057), and the comments below it (if you can't find "Configuration Manager").

Tools -> Options -> check the box in the bottom left -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> Show advanced build configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think any conversion is necessary as long as you built it with 'Any CPU'. This option can be accessed through the project properties windows -> build tab -> Platform target dropdown.

However, the option to change the target platform is not available if you're running VS Express edition.

Comment: [Not always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177275/is-there-a-difference-between-a-32-bit-net-application-and-a-64-bit-net-applic) Any CPU is enough

Comment: I just noticed that my program has the following `using Microsoft.Win32`. Not sure if I have to do anything about it

Comment: [It seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982625/why-is-there-no-microsoft-win64-namespace) you don't have to do

Answer (score 0):

Additional info regarding when to specifically target 64x rather than 'Any CPU', although it doesn't seem it now, this would have to change if you were intending to use 64x DLL's (would have added this as a comment, but I think it is extremely useful).

[When to target x64 in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436363/when-to-target-x64-in-visual-studio)